# Facebook Connect dialog box

Tags: facebook

Our programer built a facebook connect feature on our website.

The steps:
1.  User clicks the facebook connect
2.  The user gets a popup with user/pass request from facebook
3.  The user gets another popup to authorized the permissions and connect

I'm wondering how we can control the content on that 3rd pop-up pages.

Currently it says something like "Install MyWebsiteName?"  I'm wondering if that language can be changed.

Thanks!

Comment: This might depend on the locale of the user and not your applications settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure a lot of what the authorization popup does via your app settings.  Goto `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/APPID/auth` and customize it there.

Languages can be done using the "Translate you app" link in the left column of that same link above.